# Grouping in haskell regular expressions

Tags: regex, haskell

How can I extract a string using regular expressions in Haskell?

```
let x = "xyz abc" =~ "(\\w+) \\w+" :: String
```

That doesn't event get a match

```
let x = "xyz abc" =~ "(.*) .*" :: String
```

That does but x ends up as "xyz abc" how do I extract only the first regex group so that x is "xyz"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wrote/maintain such packages as [regex-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-base), [regex-pcre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre), and [regex-tdfa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa).

In regex-base the [Text.Regex.Base.Context](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-Context.html) module documents the large number of instances of RegexContext that =~ uses.  These are implemented on top of [RegexLike](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#t:RegexLike) which provides the underlying way to call matchText and matchAllText.

The [[String]] that KennyTM mentions is another instance of RegexContext, and may or may not be one that works best for you.  A comprehensive instance is

```
RegexContext a b (AllTextMatches (Array Int) (MatchText b))

type MatchText source = Array Int (source, (MatchOffset, MatchLength))
```

which can be used to get a [MatchText](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#t:MatchText) for everything:

```
let x :: Array Int (MatchText String)
    x = getAllTextMatches $ "xyz abc" =~ "(\\w+) \\w+"
```

At which point x is an Array Int of matches of an Array Int of group-matches.

Note that "\w" is Perl syntax so you need regex-pcre to access it.  If you want Unix/Posix extended regular expressions you should use regex-tdfa which is cross-platform and avoid using regex-posix that hits each platform's bugs in implementing the regex.h library.

Note that Perl vs Posix is not just a matter of syntax like "\w".  They use very different algorithms and often return different results.  Also, the time and space complexity are very different.  For matching against a string of length 'n' Perl style (regex-pcre) can be O(exp(n)) in time while Posix style using regex-posix is always O(n) in time.

Answer (score 18):

Cast the result as `[[String]]`. Then you'll get a list of matches, each being the list of matched text and the captured subgroups.

```
Prelude Text.Regex.PCRE> "xyz abc more text" =~ "(\\w+) \\w+" :: [[String]]
[["xyz abc","xyz"],["more text","more"]]
```

Comment: What's the magic behind changing function based on type?